# how to prevent the character "e" from being pasted on in the input field in vue js

Tags: html, vue.js, events, input

```
 <vs-input
                  :value="contract.value"
                  :class="isMobileOnly ? 'w-full' : 'w-1/2'"
                  class="mx-auto"
                  type="number"
                  :id="`value-${index}`"
                  onkeydown="return event.keyCode !== 69"
                  placeholder="Value"
                  @change="changeValue(index)"
                />
```

The `onkeydown` event prevents `e` from being typed into the input field but you can still paste `e` into the input field. How can I make the input field to stop accepting `e`, even when you paste the character itself.

Comment: You need to listen to the `paste` event and then strip the character from the input value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead preventing that two things separately, you can just replace all "e" characters with an empty string:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" v-model="text" />
    <div>Value is: {{ text }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref, watchEffect } from "vue";

export default {
  setup() {
    const text = ref("");

    watchEffect(() => {
      text.value = text.value.replace(/e/, "");
    });

    return { text };
  },
};
</script>
```

Demo:

https://codesandbox.io/s/prevent-e-character-lzi1o